# Coalesce field based on certain character

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a data set with

```
[TELEPHONE1] [TELEPHONE2] [TELEPHONE3]
NULL         75471512454  1254875421
125454547    NULL         7465457112
NULL         NULL         7457512124
```

I would like to extract this into two columns

```
[MOBILE]    [HOME]
75471512454 1254875421
7465457112  1254545471   
7457512124  NULL
```

[Mobile] will be any number starting with '7' [Home] will be any number that starts with anything else

I'm thinking the Coalesce function will get the 1st non null value.. but is there a way to make it pick up the 1st non null value that contains a given character / number?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `case` expressions like so:

```
select 
    Mobile = case 
      when left(Telephone1,1)='7' then Telephone1
      when left(Telephone2,1)='7' then Telephone2
      when left(Telephone3,1)='7' then Telephone3
      else null 
      end
  , Home = case 
      when left(Telephone1,1)='7' then coalesce(Telephone2,Telephone3)
      when left(Telephone2,1)='7' then coalesce(Telephone1,Telephone3)
      when left(Telephone3,1)='7' then coalesce(Telephone1,Telephone2)
      else null 
      end
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/AOWK37324

returns:

```
+-------------+------------+
|   Mobile    |    Home    |
+-------------+------------+
| 75471512454 | 1254875421 |
|  7465457112 | 125454547  |
|  7457512124 | NULL       |
+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

`COALESCE` is nothing else but multiple `case when`, so you could modify the inner logic to:

```
case when TELEPHONE1 like '7%' THEN TELEPHONE1
     when TELEPHONE2 like '7%' THEN TELEPHONE2
     when TELEPHONE3 like '7%' THEN TELEPHONE3
     else NULL
end as MOBILE,

case when ISNUMERIC(TELEPHONE1) =1 AND TELEPHONE1 not like '7%' THEN TELEPHONE1
     when ISNUMERIC(TELEPHONE2) =1 AND TELEPHONE2 not like '7%' THEN TELEPHONE2
     when ISNUMERIC(TELEPHONE3) =1 AND TELEPHONE3 not like '7%' THEN TELEPHONE3
     else NULL
end as HOME
```